# How the vine or instgram's video playing?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

Can you tell me that Vine or Instgram's video playing feature for iPhone? Are they playing the video files on server or downloading the video files to device and then playing them? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to decompile vine using hopper and found that they are using AVPlayer for playing videos.

1. When a cell become visible they start downloading video from server and save it to cache folder. If video already exist in cache downloading is not done.

2.Then they create AVMutableComposition from that single video file, by repeating it 30 times.

3.Then they use avplayer to play.

If you keep vine video playing, it will stop after 30 loops.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of reverse engineering.

I'd start by getting the Vine app. It would help a lot of you have a jailbroken device, as you can use GDB or LLDB to dump the decrypted executable.

Then, you can use a disassembler like Hopper or IDA to figure out how the app works. I'd highly recommend learning ARM assembly. Best thing that happened to me since I learned C.